# Remove need for instance name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

Currently to connect to my SQLEXPRESS server I need to do the following:

```
152.152.152.152\SQLEXPRESS
```

Can I do anything so it removes the need to specify the "\SQLEXPRESS" part and just connect with IP address?

Thanks Paul

Comment: Where are you connecting from? The SQL Server Management Studio? An application?

Comment: You should look at [default vs. named instances](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165614.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable TCP protocol on the instance and assign ports it listens on. Then you will be able to just connect to it using the IP address and port number.

You can use SQL Server Configuration Manager to do it, just see [1].

After that you just connect using TCP/IP, like in this example **tcp:127.0.0.1,1433**.

Note that if the port is 1433, like in this example, you can just omit it, like this **tcp:127.0.0.1**.

If you want to connect from remote machines you need to open the port on the firewall as well.

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177440.aspx